# html-css-how to make opeanable vertical menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to make a menu like this image :

[image]

When I hover on each item on right menu , it opens a box beside it.As you can see, when mouse hover on each menu , it opens a box beside the menu and it come over other elements on the site .

I've done somethings but nothing near it .

Comment: we need to see the code, until and unless we cant give suggestions, try to show some demo / code.. with only image cant give answer..

Comment: Can u post some code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you correct try with this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div>something</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <div>something</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    float: right;
}

ul li > div {
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

ul li:hover > div {
    display: block;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
```

The `ul` is the menu and the `div` is the white box. He will get visible on hover. For better view add css.

If you have other markup please provide it.

**EDIT:**
https://jsfiddle.net/58hzg54c/