# How can i make a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

[image: Here is my nav]

CSS

```
.nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0%;     
}
.nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    /*top: -124px;*/
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 2px #009759 solid;
}
.nav ul li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;

    border-radius: 0px;
}
.nav ul li a
{
    color: #009759;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav ul li active {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

What is the best way to make a dropdown menu from one of my header menu buttons? I inlcuded my CSS file for the header but now I need you to tell me how to make a dropdown.

Comment: Similar question with jsfiddle here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979281/html-css-how-to-make-opeanable-vertical-menu

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dropdown in many ways.. the usual method is by making javascript codes that will handle the hover event on the selected menu..

there are many good tutorials online that can help you.. like this [dropdown with javascript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa218659(v=office.11).aspx)

but if you are looking for pure css dropdown, you can also look at this link: [dropdown pure css](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jquery for this. I have done this before, and while it may seem a bit crude with the code, it works wonderfully.

```
$(".nav ul, .nav ul li, .nav ul li a").hide();
$(".nav").hover(function(){
   $(".nav ul, .nav ul li, .nav ul li a").show(500);
});
```

Comment: Am not that good with Jquery yet but will try and implement this. Thanks

Comment: Here is a good dropdown menu: http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu